# Adding numbers of the same length to a dictionary as values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a Python list:

```py
list_1 = [1, 2, 3, 11, 22, 33, 111, 222, 3333, 2222, 1111, 333]
```

I want to return a dictionary whose keys are the length of the items in the list and values are lists having items of same length as key.

sample output is as shown:

```py
Dict_1 = {1 : [1,2,3],2:[11,22,33],3:[111,222,333]...}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's prob. easier to just use the power of *itertools* **groupby** to solve this:

Notes - it's based on the assumption that the input list is orderly, meaning  each item are in ordered fashion. Otherwise, it's expected to *sort* it first.
Thanks for the comments/feedback by @S.B

The rest of formatting and putting into the outputs is left as an exercise. ;-)  *(Can you try it now?)*

```py
# L is your input list

from itertools import groupby

dc = dict()

for k, g in groupby(L, key=lambda x: len(str(x))):
    print(k, list(g))
```

Output:

```
1 [1, 2, 3]
2 [11, 22, 33]
3 [111, 222]
4 [3333, 2222, 1111]
3 [333]
```

Comment: Great. Just to mention, this would work if items are already in correct place. Otherwise a sort step is required.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [1, 2, 3, 11, 22, 33, 111, 222, 3333, 2222, 1111, 333]

d = defaultdict(list)
for item in lst:
    d[len(str(item))].append(item)

print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dict_1 = {}

for i in list_1:
   if len(i) not in Dict_1:
      Dict_1[len(i)] = [i]
   else:
      Dict_1[len(i)].append(i)

print(Dict_1)
```